# Run function once per visit

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi and thanks in advance of any support on this.

I have a site where I'm offering to send US visitors back to our US specific website via a Modal popup qwhen they land on our AU site.

I only want the script to run once per visit.

What would I need to add to below to achieve this?

Thanks (ps- very new to ajax and anything outside HTML / CSS)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.ipstack.com/check?access_key=##hidden##',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(location) {
      // AU -- Australia
      if (location.country_code === 'AU') {

      } else {
        // Reveal Modal to select AU or US store

        // Modal 1
        $('#popup-2').slickModals({
          popupType: 'delayed',
          delayTime: 0,
          overlayColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
          popupWidth: '420px',
          popupHeight: 'auto',
          popupLocation: 'topCenter',
          popupAnimationDuration: '0.4',
          popupAnimationEffect: 'slideTop',
          popupMargin: '30px',
          popupPadding: '20px',
          mobileBreakPoint: '420px',
          mobileLocation: 'topCenter',
          mobileWidth: '100%',
          mobileHeight: 'auto',
          mobilePadding: '0px',
          reopenClass: 'openSlickModal-2'

        })
      }
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: How do you define a _"visit"_? What constitutes the end of a visit?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a *"visit"* is any browser session which ends when the tab / browser is closed, you can use [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to store a flag.

For example

```js
if (!sessionStorage.getItem('redirect-offered')) {
    $.ajax(...)
}
```

and in your *success* handler

```js
if (location.country_code === 'AU') {

} else {
  // the value doesn't really matter, it just has to be "truthy"
  sessionStorage.setItem('redirect-offered', 1); 

  $('#popup-2').slickModals(...)
}
```

Full code example here ~ https://pastebin.com/X7Jy7BD2

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response Phil. Sorry to be a pest, but how would your suggested additions look in my code above. Do add them in or replace something. Sorry total newby here

Comment: @DieselHashtag the first block is an `if` that wraps your whole `$.ajax(...)` code. The second block adds a line under the `else` in your _success_ handler

Comment: Phil, you're a champ. Thanks so much, working a treat. Wish I'd jumped on here much earlier!!! Thanks a million!

Comment: Sorry one more thing on this Phil! What if I was to reverse it and say 'if doesn't equal a) or b).. for example if (location.country_code != 'CA' || 'US' ) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('redirect-offered', 1);   .....   this doesn't seem to be working though? Am I losing the multiple Values incorrectly? Thanks again

Comment: @DieselHashtag that's not how you write a Boolean expression. It would be `if (location.country_code != 'CA' || location.country_code != 'US')`. You could also use an array, like `if (!['CA', 'US'].includes(location.country_code))`

Comment: Ok great. Thanks again, working a treat with your second option. Much appreciated.